# Sharepoint converts certain keyboard characters like "<" , ">" , " to the escape character

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-editor-web-part

Hi I am using SharePoint Server 2013 On Premise.
The issue is that when I edit the page and try to edit content editor using Edit source,then certain characters undergo transformation and are converted to HTML character entity or entity number for example:

```
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor< > ' & commodo consequat.</p>
```

changes to :

```
<p>&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor &lt; &gt; &#39; &amp; commodo consequat.</p>
```

Does anyone knows why this happens and If we can get rid of this issue ?

[image: Edit Source]

Comment: What happens after you save the content editor webpart changes and page? Does it still show the `<>` on SP page?

Comment: Yes, after saving and publishing the page, I see < and > symbols in there default format but while editing source they are changed to there HTML entity format.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge that is a by-design behavior for converting special characters. The less-than sign < and greater-than sign > They are at the core of the syntax of the HTML code. The browser will assume you are using tags.

You should never use them in the readable portions of your web page without encoding them first for proper display.

Reference: https://www.lifewire.com/special-characters-in-html-3466714